# Unity - healthbar as outlined line around the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have a game in Unity.
The idea of the game is that an object is spawned on the screen.
It exists for several seconds.
You need to click on it, while it exists.

What I want to do, is that while it exists - I want to show a timer, but not with numbers, but with an outlined line on the perimeter of the screen.

I know, how to make a make a slider and how to make circular health bar, yet I do not really have an idea to make a slider, that is decresing from everywhere to the centre as you can see on the screenshots below.

I would be thankful for the inspiration!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a dumb and simple approach:

Have two images with fill, one goes middle towards top the other middle towards bottom.

Just imagine the pnguin is your outline ^^

[image]

Comment: the problem is that I need a lign to go like a snake on the perimeter. So it starts in the center,  goes vertically and riches the top corner and then goes to the center diagonally

Comment: Actually, eventually, I will take this solution as the easiest one

Answer (score 2):

This should be a very good fit using alpha cutoff with a custom shader.

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnAoD7hgDxw) explaining it in detail (it's only the first half you will need).

The basic idea is to create a texture with a graded alpha depending on how you want the texture to appear/disappear. In this case the alpha value at the top and the bottom would be close to 0 and then gradually around the line on both sides towards the middle increase to 1. The shader then cuts off the texture below a cutoff threshold which you can change depending on the value of the timer.

Comment: Great solution and idea, actually, yet I don't have that much time and experience to do it quickly and easily, but thank you!